# How to make a column sortable(Gridview widget)

Tags: gridview, yii2

Maybe I need to make changes to the search model? 
View index file:

```js
<?= 
  GridView::widget([
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
  'filterModel' => $searchModel,
  'columns' => 
   [
    //'address'
    [
      'label' => 'address',
      'value' => function($model)
      {
        return
          $model->payment_method.' '.
          $model->payment_address_1.' '.
          $model->payment_address_2.' '.
          $model->payment_city.' '.
          $model->payment_postcode.' '.
          $model->payment_country.' '.
        $model->payment_zone.' ';
      },
    ],
  ]
?>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////

Answer (score 0):

You just add in your search model like:

```
public function search($params)
{
  ......

  $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['your_column_name'=>SORT_DESC]],
  ]);

  ......
}
```